# How to update JSON column in oracle 12.1

Tags: json, oracle

Am trying to update a JSON column in oracle 12.1. Is there any json function that can be used to update the JSON. I have added a constraint JSON_COLUMN is JSON.

I have tried :

```
UPDATE tablename SET JSON =
json_mergepatch(JSON, '{"STRUCTURE_NAME":null}');
```

But this function is applicable only for 19c

```
This "STRUCTURE_NAME": "ABC:STATE:L12345", needs to be updated with "STRUCTURE_NAME":null
```

Answer (score 3):

Pre-19c, if you want to change any values in a JSON document, you have to replace the whole thing:

```
create table t (
  doc varchar2(100)
    check ( doc is json ) 
);

insert into t values ('{
  "changeMe" : "to null",
  "leaveMe"  : "alone"
}');

update t
set    doc = '{
  "changeMe" : null,
  "leaveMe"  : "alone"
}';

select * from t;

DOC                                               
{
  "changeMe" : null,
  "leaveMe"  : "alone"
}
```

Note that when you get to 19c and use `json_mergepatch`, setting an attribute to `null` removes it from the document:

```
update t
set    doc = json_mergepatch ( 
  doc, 
  '{
    "changeMe" : null
  }');

select * from t;

DOC                   
{"leaveMe":"alone"}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris - The JSON which am trying to update is around 5MB , sorting in a JSON format would result in 53K lines . I would like to update just a parameter :  
Updated  JSON:[SOURCE_SYSTEM] been updated to null:
"Type": "DROP",
   "SOURCE_SYSTEM": "NULL",
   "TYPE": "ABCD"

Can we update just the parameter , rather than using the whole JSON:
UPDATE tbl SET DOCUMENT_COLUMN = REPLACE(JSON, SOURCE_SYSTEM, 'NULL');

Comment: JSON is just text, so in theory yes. You have to be sure there's nothing else in the document matching the replace though!

Comment: JSON:
"node": [{
            "Type": "DROP",
   "Links": "",
   "VERSION_ID": 12345678,
   "ID": "12345678",
   "CAB_ID": "650252419",
   "AEND": "ABC_123456",
   "BEND": "650252418",
   "SEQUENCE_NO": 0,
   "STATUS": "SUCCESS",
   "DEL_FLAG": "2019-03-25T19:36:26Z",
   "CUR_WO_ID": 123456,
   "CREATED_DT": "2018-12-19T16:21:54Z",
   "MODIFIED_DT": "2019-02-06T14:23:00Z",
   "SOURCE_SYSTEM": "NULL",
   "TYPE": "ABCD"
           {] 
UPDATE tablename SET JSON = REPLACE(JSON, 'node.STATUS', 'REVERTED') ;This hasn't helped. It has shown 1 row updated , but hasn't got updated.

Comment: That's because there's no string `node.STATUS` in your JSON! You can't use JSON path expressions in `replace`. You need to search for the exact text in the document you want to change. e.g. if in your example you want `"TYPE": "ABCD"` to become null, you need to `REPLACE(JSON, '"TYPE": "ABCD"', '"TYPE": null')`. Or just `REPLACE(JSON, '"ABCD"', 'null')` and hope "ABCD" is nowhere else in the document!

Comment: Yes , It has worked . Any way to update with the JSON path expression in 12.1

Comment: No, you have to replace the whole document

Answer (score 0):

Below query will overwrite the JSON document column for all rows.

```
UPDATE JSON_TABLE
SET JSON_DOC_COL=JSON_OBJECT('name' VALUE var_name,
                             'age' VALUE var_age);
```

To append the JSON document column, below query can be used.

```
UPDATE JSON_TABLE
SET JSON_DOC_COL=JSON_MERGEPATCH(JSON_DOC_COL,JSON_OBJECT('name' VALUE var_name,
                             'age' VALUE var_age) RETURNING CLOB);
```