# Updating json array of objects in Oracle

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql, sql-update

Hi I have a json column in Oracle database with a data like [{"id":100, "make":"BMW"},{"id":110,"make":"mercedes"}]..... now how can I update the make of object with id 110 to Toyota using sql/plsql..Thank you..

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update JSON column in oracle 12.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58114909/how-to-update-json-column-in-oracle-12-1)

Comment: You can do it with [SQL function `json_transform`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/adjsn/oracle-sql-function-json_transform.html#GUID-7BED994B-EAA3-4FF0-824D-C12ADAB862C1) , which is available in the Oracle Database 20c preview and will be in the 21c release.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_table()` function for version 12.1.0.2+ to parse a json column. Btw, a string type column such as `clob`, `varchar2` might be checked out by adding a check constraint for concerned string type column. So use :

```
update tab
   set jsdata=(select case when js.id = 110 then replace(jsdata,js.make,'toyota') end
                 from tab
                cross join
                      json_table(jsdata, '$[*]'
                         columns(make    varchar2(50) path '$.make',
                                 id      int path '$.id')) js
                where js.id = 110   )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ece1ede4434916beb283ba8f79f2c592)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not easy to change data within an array.

```
create table t(
  id number primary key,
  json_ds varchar2(4000) check(json_ds is json)
);
insert into t values (1, '[{"id":100, "make":"BMW"},{"id":110,"make":"mercedes"}]');
commit;

update /*+ WITH_PLSQL */ t a
set json_ds = (
  with function update_json(p_in in varchar2) return varchar2 is
    l_ja json_array_t;
    l_po json_object_t;
    l_id number;
  begin
    l_ja := json_array_t.parse(p_in);
    for i in 0..l_ja.get_size - 1 loop
      l_po := json_object_t(l_ja.get(i));
      l_id := l_po.get_number('id');
      if l_id = 110 then
        l_po.put('make', 'Toyota');
      end if;
    end loop;
    return l_ja.to_string;
  end update_json;
  select update_json(a.json_ds) from dual
)
where id = 1;
/
select * from t;

ID  JSON_DS
1   [{"id":100,"make":"BMW"},{"id":110,"make":"Toyota"}]
```

Best regards, Stew Ashton

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON_TRANSFORM() in 19.8 and up.

```
with example as
 (select '[{"id":100, "make":"BMW"},{"id":110,"make":"mercedes"}]' as json from dual)
select json_transform(example.json, set '$[*]?(@.id==110).make' = 'Toyota') as newjson from example;
```

Output:

> [{"id":100,"make":"BMW"},{"id":110,"make":"Toyota"}]

You can also use JSON_MERGEPATCH (19c and up) but it can't update within arrays, need to update the whole array

Regards